# Is there anyone who is familiar with this Error in the Simulator (dialog flow console)

Tags: simulator, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

From the below scenario, we can see that the Route is actually transitioned to end the flow, which in fact is ending the session(see in the simulator). What could be the reason behind it? Any help is much appreciated, Thanks in Advance!!

[Click here for image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8eiG.png)
[Agent layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4L5K.jpg)

Comment: it depends from how your flows are set up: if the flow containing this page is the only one you have dialogflow will kill the session since it has no flow to get back to. can you clarify what your question is and what is your agent's layout?

Comment: @fcagnola Thank you for responding, there are multiple pages in the flow and if I am not wrong it has to go to the start pages instead of ending the session. Please view the layout in the image reference

Comment: no, that's what i'm telling you: from your image i can only see you're in the "Default start flow". If you had another flow, and went to "End flow" you'd get back to the default start flow, but since you only have a single flow when you close it the conversation/session is also closed. This is the right behavior.  If you want it to go to the start page just select that instead of end flow on your transition routes.

Comment: @fcagnola Thanks for the reply, do you want me to transition it to the start page instead of the end flow to avoid ending the session?

Comment: that would be my advice, if your aim is to have that behavior you should do that. Pay attention that by returning to start page you're not deleting session-related information: any parameters you filled will be available and the bot won't ask again (this could result in weird behaviour)